# What makes ID3 timed metadata unique?

Tags: video-streaming, http-live-streaming, id3, video-ads

I am new to learning server side ad insertion concepts. It makes use of ID3 timed metadata to uniquely identify each user's video session. How does it uniquely identifies user's video session? Is it because ID3 timed metadata is unique in nature? If yes, then what parameters make it unique?

Comment: It’s not unique unless you give every user a different packaged stream.

Comment: thanks szatmary! can you please a little bit more?

Comment: A little bit more what?

Comment: Can you pls explain a bit more about how the users are given different packaged stream and what aspect of it makes it unique?

Comment: If you make a stream for every users, then every user can have a unique stream. But that not a common practice.

Comment: So i am assuming there is a unique ID attached to each stream for every user?

Comment: If that’s what you want to d,o or you can just put a timed marker, the same one for everyone, that triggers the code to run an ad. This code can then do whatever targeting you want.